# Difference between readAsBinaryString and readAsText using FileReader

Tags: javascript, string, html, utf, typed-arrays

So as an example, when I read the π character (`\u03C0`) from a File using the FileReader API, I get the pi character back to me when I read it using `FileReader.readAsText(blob)` which is expected. But when I use `FileReader.readAsBinaryString(blob)`, I get the result `\xcf\x80` instead, which doesn't seem to have any visible correlation with the pi character. What's going on? (This probably has something to do with the way UTF-8/16 is encoded...)

Comment: `CF80` is the UTF-8 encoding for π.

Comment: ...that was probably too obvious, but you can post that as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, if that's all you needed... :)

`CF80` is the UTF-8 encoding for π.

Answer (score 22):

`FileReader.readAsText` takes the encoding of the file into account. In particular, since you have the file encoded in UTF-8, there may be multiple bytes per character. Reading it as text, the UTF-8 is read as it is, and you get your string.

`FileReader.readAsBinaryString`, on the other hand, does exactly what it says. It reads the file byte by byte. It doesn't recognise multi-byte characters, which in particular is good news for binary files (basically anything except a text file). Since π is a two-byte character, you get the two individual bytes that make it up in your string.

This difference can be seen in many places. In particular when encoding is lost and you see characters like é displayed as Ã©.

Comment: thanks...so when I try to append \xA2 to a BlobBuilder it turns out as \xC2\xA2 because that's what it is UTF-8 encoded, but how can I get back \xA2? (it's a single-byte character)

Comment: oh, I guess I have to use an ArrayBuffer then