# Error reading binary file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, filereader

I'm trying to read and write a binary file (fingerprint). The contents of binary files are below:

> tL.|¢Tn>ªÏû•"q‚º†k‹ë²¶zño‰JÇ5»

I read this file with the following command:

```
var input, file, fr; 
input = document.getElementById('fileinput'); 
file = input.files[0]; 
fr = new FileReader(); 
fr.onload = receivedBinary; 
fr.readAsBinaryString(file);     

function receivedBinary() {
    showResult(fr, "Binary");
}

function showResult(fr, label) {
    var result;
    result = fr.result;
    alert(result);    
 }
```

But it's happening a problem. When I see the file content that has been read, some characters are not loaded. The following file after read:

> tL.|¢Tn>ªÏû"qºkë²¶zñoJÇ5»

For example, do you realize that the symbol "•", between characters **û** and **"** was not read.

Why? What should I do to read and write all the characters?

Comment: These differences are often due to character encoding. If it's a binary file, why are you trying to read it as a _String_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between readAsBinaryString and readAsText using FileReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346052/difference-between-readasbinarystring-and-readastext-using-filereader)

Comment: Then, what command must I use instead readAsBinaryString?

Comment: Uhm, alerting binary is probably not a very good form of debugging

Comment: Try to use Uint8Array